# Exclude folder from directory listing in apache2

Tags: apache-2.4

I know I can disable directory listings with

```
Options -Indexes
```

in a `<Location>` or `<Directory>`, but I want the listing to happen.
The issue is that I am hosting files on my server. But I also have a web interface for pihole running on there. So I set up a rule that forbids `/admin` and `/pihole` to be accessed except from the local network:

```
<Location ~ "/(pihole|admin)">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from 192.168.1
</Location>
```

This removes the entries from the directory listing, too. However it generates an access denied entry every in the `error.log` time someone calls the directory listing from remote:

```
[Fri Jan 24 18:13:00.582417 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 1633] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:60484] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/pihole/
```

This in turn upsets fail2ban and it bans people just for looking at the listing they're supposed to be allowed to view.

So how do I fix that?

My idea was to simply exclude the two entries from the listing to begin with. But I don't know how to do that.
I have tried

```
<Location ~ "/(pihole|admin)">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

But it still generates the access denied log entries and bans me after 5 tries.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by setting up 2 virtual hosts. one for the file hosting and one for pihole. I keep them apart with two different dns entries.
It's a workaround for the question and doesn't really answer it, but it's a solution I am more content with than what I asked for.